# Monitoring properties of object in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a container view controller, that adds 3 set view controller's views to it's view and sets its frame, somewhere between that and the views actually appearing, the views' frames change, and expand to the maximum frame (1024,768).

How do I go about find where and when these changes are made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `setFrame:` on a subclass of `UIView`, make sure those controllers are instantiating views that are the same type of your subclass, and then put a breakpoint on `setFrame:`.  The implementation would simply be:

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)newRect {
  [super setFrame:newRect];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been bugging for a while! If only there was built in functionality in Xcode.

Comment: If only I could do this with the view from a subclass of UINavigationController. Somewhere between `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews:` the frame is changing from (0 20; 320 44) to (0 0; 320 44), causing it to jump immediately following a view controller transition. It is bugging me and I can't seem to track down why or where the actual change is happening.

Comment: Update: Problem solved! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795645/uinavigationbar-jumps-20pixels-during-transitionfromviewcontroller